# Can't use @Autowired in desktop application

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, desktop-application

i am trying to use spring in desktop application, but i am facing a problem with autowiring in action methods of my **JPanel**.

i am loading the applicationContext in my main method as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
            MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    Signup signup = new Signup();
    frame.add(signup);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("Please input your data");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 180);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

and i can see that it's loaded with no problems.

**my panel code:**

```
@Component
public class Signup extends JPanel {


    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    public Signup() {



        JButton btn_submit = new JButton("Submit");
        btn_submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                registerUser();
            }
        });



    }

    private void registerUser() {

        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.setName(username);
        newUser.setSalary(salary);
        userDao.addUser(newUser);

    }
}
```

the `context:component-scan` is configured properly, and i am using `context:annotation-config` too but i always gets **NullPointerException** in `userDao.addUser(newUser);`
which means that the Dependency Injection is not working as it should.

please advise how to fix this issue.

**UPDATE:** applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="${project.groupId}" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>

                <value>classpath:messages/application.properties</value>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="${project.groupId}.domain" />


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
                hibernate.show_sql=false
                hibernate.format_sql=false
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
            </value>
        </property>

    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />

        <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:test" />

        <property name="username" value="root" />

        <property name="password" value="root" />

    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


</beans>
```

Comment: Care to share your Spring config?

Comment: @GaryF, not so much to tell about it, but anyway i shared it.

Comment: Which concrete subclass of UserDao do you expect to be injected? Can you please provide the code for that class? What package is it in? What is the value of project.groupId?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are going to configure Spring in a desktop environment, then ***you*** must be the one to work with the `ApplicationContext`.

For example, if you want to get a hold of your `Signup` class that you have posted here, you would do something like this in your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
    Signup signup = appContext.getBean(Signup.class);
    //use signup here...
}
```

Using `new Signup()` to get a new instance of the `Signup` class, which won't work the way you want, because you want it to be a Spring managed class!  (Actually, you could get it to work that way, but that is beyond my answer here)

Comment: that's an answer of an experienced person, you found out the error without me posting it, thank a lot, it's a silly mistake from me.